# Handling text data with Tensorflow 2 "ERROR: Attempted to pad to a smaller size than the input element"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tensorflow-datasets

I'm getting this error while iterating through a tokenized text dataset:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Attempted to pad to a smaller size than the input element

It probably stems from the fact that I simply cannot understand the `padded_shapes=([None], (1,))` argument. Here's the [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N8WCMci_jpDHwCVgSED-B9yts-q9_Bb5/view) and the code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from collections import Counter

os.chdir('/home/nicolas/Documents/Datasets')

data = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset('rotten_tomatoes_string.csv',
                                       record_defaults=[tf.string, tf.string],
                                       header=True, select_cols=[0, 1])  

review_tokenizer= tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()
vocabulary = Counter()

for ix, (_, review) in enumerate(data):
    review = tf.strings.lower(review)
    tokens = review_tokenizer.tokenize(review.numpy())
    vocabulary.update(tokens)

vocabulary = [key for (key, value) in vocabulary.items() if value >= 5 and len(key) > 2]

ratings = {'rotten', 'fresh'}
review_encoder = tfds.features.text.TokenTextEncoder(vocabulary)
freshness_encoder = tfds.features.text.TokenTextEncoder(ratings)

def encode(freshness, review):
    review = review_encoder.encode(review.numpy())
    freshness = freshness_encoder.encode(freshness.numpy())
    return freshness, review

def tf_map(freshness, review):
    encoded_freshness, review = tf.py_function(encode,
                                               inp=[freshness, review],
                                               Tout=[tf.int32, tf.int32])
    review.set_shape([None])
    encoded_freshness.set_shape(1,)
    return encoded_freshness, review


TAKE = 480_000

train_data = data.map(tf_map).take(1000)
train_data = train_data.padded_batch(8, padded_shapes=([None], (1,)))

next(iter(train_data))
```

How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

With `padded_shapes=([None], (1,))` you are requesting the second element to be padded to size of 1. But, you should consider that:

1. The second element is the review tokens (look at the `return` statement of `tf_map` function) and it probably consists of tens or hundreds of values (for each sample).
2. The `padded_batch` method of `Dataset` does not do any truncating; it can only do padding.

Therefore, according to the two points above, you would get the mentioned error in your question. Instead, use a higher **constant** dimension size (which should be greater that the length of the all the samples in your dataset; otherwise you would get the same error), or use `[None]` to pad each batch **to the smallest size that fits** (i.e. to the maximum length of the samples in each batch).

Comment: But how do you know the size of the largest sample of the dataset?

Comment: @NicolasGervais Usually, it is not known beforehand. That's why in most of NLP tasks we fix the value of max length, and then use a combination of truncating and padding to make all the samples have exactly the same length. Alternatively, you can do this on a per-batch basis (as mentioned in the answer, with `tf.data.Dataset` this could be achieved using `padded_batch` method and shape of `[None]`).